# Web Portal: How useful is the local time?

Tags: javascript, date, localization

I'm just working on a website dealing with javascript local dates/times. Dates/Times are stored as UTC in database and are calculated via date-object (js) to user's local time zone.
I see that many websites, forums, and platforms don't use these local times but a countdown-like expression, for example

**"posted 1 month ago", "posted 3 hours ago",** ... and so on

Do you think there is any benefit of doing it so instead of showing the local date/time?
It would be very interesting for me what arguments you have for pro and con.
Thanks.

Comment: it is more exact if you show the user the exact date instead of just "about a year ago" but if you don't have to be exact I don't see any advantages really

Comment: From a usability point of view, no one wants to see the date. It is much nicer to just see something like "asked **today**" rather than "asked 14th Sept 2012"

Comment: Stack Overflow does it by showing relative dates, but with the real date on hover. What ever you pick, do it in JS, not on the server. Also, this is a bit too discussiony, as it doesn't have an actual answer, so it might get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly a usability issue. If you show local date/time, your users will face the cognitive load of having to figure out the relationship of the time displayed to the current wall clock time.

Personally I think these relative time indications are OK, but you should have them properly localized whenever possible. They drag in some of the less understood I18N/L10N issues like replaceable parameters and singular/plural forms.

Answer (score 2):

For me "posted 1 month ago" is better detail than the time because i have to calculate the age of the article. But there might be use cases where a person might want to know the exact date of the article when comparing with other articles on the same topic. so its up to the nature of the article.

Answer (score 0):

For some kind of blogs can be good. In comments not always. Sometimes is good to see a precise time.

Also depends on target users, for example, regular people like it, programmers doesn't care of it at all.

Answer (score 0):

The local time in JavaScript is derived from client's clock. This doesn't necessarily mean that this time is the actual local time. Think about a business man travelling from Paris to New York. He might want to keep the laptop's clock to have the Paris time, since he wants to stay in touch with his family, but on his smartphone, he uses the New York time, for business relations.

Relative temporal descriptions like "3 minutes ago" are very helpful to distinguish between old and new, imminent and far in the future events. Since they are relative, they are valid in any time zone.